# Loose Moen single handle faucet

Tags: faucet

[image]

Can't seem to figure out how to tighten this. The whole thing has become loose up top. It's in a new (3 yrs) house

Answer (score 1):

Moen has an actual socket to tighten the nut in question. I have also been able to tighten them with a small, 6", adjustable wrench. The Moen tool can usually be picked up at your home store or a plumbing supply store. here's what the tool looks like:

[image]

You could also use a deep socket if you are a tool collector. Good luck

Comment: A common basin wrench should also work to tighten it a little.  Their size makes it a pain to fully install one of these faucets, but you can fuss with it to get a few turns on that nut.

Comment: A "crow's foot" wrench works well in the absence of the original tool.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response folks.

I was very tempted to pick up a "crows foot" set. I had never seen those before. But after reading the comment about a "basin wrench", I suddenly remembered that a long time ago a guy gave me one of those and it's been tucked away in an old toolbox for literally decades. I drug it out and what do you know, it finally got put to good use!! And just like jPhi1618 said, it was tricky to get positioned in that tight space, but I was able to get a grip and a few turns, enough to get that thing tightened. So we're good to go.

Thanks for all the replies!!